# Struts2 jQuery grid plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts

I have an arraylist of type userDetails class. The userDetails class has 3 fields user id,user name and user city

I want to populate arraylist users in a grid using the jQuery plugin.

```
  <sjg:grid gridModel="users"  caption="Users"
            dataType="json"
            href="%{remoteurl}"
            pager="true"
            rowList="10,15,20"
            rowNum="15"
            rownumbers="true"
            onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"

          >
  <sjg:gridColumn name="userId" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
  <sjg:gridColumn name="userName" index="name" title="User Name" sortable="true"/>
  <sjg:gridColumn name="userCity" index="name" title="User City" sortable="true"/>
  </sjg:grid>
```

This is what I did. But the users are not getting displayed in the grid.

Any suggestions on what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: please post your action class, which indicates `%{remoteurl}`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing gridModel and index attributes like this:

```
<sjg:grid gridModel="gridModel"  caption="Users"
            dataType="json"
            href="%{remoteurl}"
            pager="true"
            rowList="10,15,20"
            rowNum="15"
            rownumbers="true"
            onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"

          >
     <sjg:gridColumn name="userId" index="userId" title="ID" 
                     formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
     <sjg:gridColumn name="userName" index="userName" 
                     title="User Name" sortable="true"/>
     <sjg:gridColumn name="userCity" index="userCity" 
                     title="User City" sortable="true"/>
  </sjg:grid>
```